# Significance of the 1st order statistic

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have a bundle of 20 sticks of various lengths, and I am told that the lengths of all the sticks in this sample is well described by a Gaussian distribution with a certain mean and standard deviation.

I am asked to determine the expected length of the shortest stick in the bundle.

Am I correct in thinking that this is where the 1st order statistic is used? I already know how this is calculated, but I just want to confirm that this is what it is used for.

As an aside: could someone intuitively explain why it is not simply the case that you would find the value corresponding to the point along the Gaussian curve which exceeds (in this case) 95% of the area under the curve? My feeling is that the two answers would be in the same ballpark, but that this approach is still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your aside:

Your intuition relating quantiles and order statistics has two difficulties.  First

- The 5% quantile is the (1) upper bound of the stick lengths you would expect 1/20 of the sticks, *drawn one at a time* to land in (if you performed an infinite number of draws).  (2) Each stick is independent of the others.
- The 1st order statistic for draws of 20 sticks is the (1) expectation value of the length of the smallest of sticks drawn 20 at a time.  (2) Each minimal stick is dependent on 19 other sticks.

That is, the (1) statements say the quantile is an upper bound, not an expectation (and expectations should be "in the middle", not "upper bounds", although sufficiently non-normal distributions...).

The (2) statements ... The first order statistic in this discussion answers a question about "1 small and 19 big" lengths, so incorporates probability data about the other 19 sticks.  The quantile just asks about one stick, so does not incorporate data about any other sticks.  (You can see this in the computation.  The quantile asks how far to go along one copy of the CDF to reach 5%.  The order statistic asks how far to go to get one below and 19 above (with a binomial coefficient to keep track of how many ways we could have labelled those 20 sticks).  The underlying computation is on a 20-dimensional product of 20 copies of the CDF.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the length of the shortest stick in the bundle is the minimum of lengths for sticks in the bundle.   That is by definition the first order statistic of the data set.

If the lengths of the twenty sticks are independent and identically distributed, then the cummulative distribution function is:

$$\mathsf P(X_{(1)}\leqslant x) ~{= 1-\mathsf P(\bigcap\nolimits_{k=1}^{20}\{X_k\gt x\}) \\= 1-\mathsf P(X_1\gt x)^{20}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I presume the lengths of the sticks are supposed to be independent.

Hint: the shortest stick has length $> x$ if and only if all $20$ sticks have length $> x$.